# Link Payment method

Tags: methods, stripe-payments, payment, subscription

Can I attach Link as payment method to a specific customer object in Stripe dashboard?

I tried creating a payment method via API but getting an error

> invalid_request_error
> You cannot create a type link PaymentMethod directly.

OR

> parameter_unknown - link[email]
> Received unknown parameter: link[email]

Following: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create

Create a Link Payment method then attach to a customer object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a Link Payment Method directly. You should use SetupIntent APIs or a `setup` mode Checkout session to save a Link Payment Method to your customer. Follow this [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) for details.

Comment: I appreciate it. All good!